# mongodb config file

Tags: mongodb

I have a strange problem with my config file:

When I try to add ANY of the following entries, the server doesn't start anymore,
I have tried to add them all together and by adding them one by one.

```
fork = true
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
port = 27017
```

If I have only the standard entries

```
dbpath
logpath
auth
rest
```

there is no problem.

This is on a windows 7 64bit system.

Comment: What build of MongoDB? Have you tried to recreate the file from scratch? What if the file just has one of those three (and uses defaults for everything else)?

Comment: my  build is 2.2.2 and yes, I have tried to add just one of those and the same problem.

Comment: now I have recreated the file and saved as UTF8 and it works. Seems that this problem has to do something with file format (stored as ANSI or as UTF8 ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fork` is not a valid Windows parameter.  See this question for a fuller description: [mongodb fork in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185012/mongodb-fork-in-windows)

You may want to consider using the YAML format for your config files.  They'll be much more readable as your configuration grows: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/