# mongodb fork in windows

Tags: mongodb

I have seen on tutorials that they use `--fork` as parameter of mongod. But when I try to do so, it says unknown option `--fork`. So how to `--fork` mongodb on windows?

Comment: yea --fork is a linux thing, I don't think there is one for windows

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`--fork` is actually a Linux command not a Windows or `mongod` command. I do not believe the same exists on Windows at all.

Linux has two primitives here, `fork` and `exec` however Windows only really has `createProcess` which is effectively `fork`-and-`exec`.

Setting up a service and running it in `fork` mode is not the same, a service is more like a `init.d` script however that is currently the only way really.

Cygwin can emulate fork on Windows, very slowly, as described here: [What is the closest thing windows has to fork()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985281/what-is-the-closest-thing-windows-has-to-fork)

Comment: Could use the start command so it starts in its on command prompt

Answer (score 24):

You can write `start /b` (/b - means execute without new cmd window) before `mongod` command. It will start your `mongod` command asynchronous and release console prompt. So, has similar effect, like `fork`.

It can be used in .bat scripts, for example, starting replica set:

> start /b mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "1.log" --dbpath data\rs1 --port 27017 --smallfiles
>
> start /b mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "2.log" --dbpath data\rs2 --port 27018 --smallfiles
>
> start /b mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "3.log" --dbpath data\rs3 --port 27019 --smallfiles
>
> ...

Comment: how would you then stop each or any of the mongods ?

Comment: mongo localhost:27017 --eval "db.adminCommand({shutdown : 1})"
mongo localhost:27018 --eval "db.adminCommand({shutdown : 1})"
mongo localhost:27019 --eval "db.adminCommand({shutdown : 1})"

Comment: not sure what version of windows and mongodb you are using but this does not work with win 7 and MongoDB v4

Answer (score 3):

**The `--fork` option is not for MongoDB for Windows users** and you must execute this every mongod command in different window:

```
mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "1.log" --dbpath /data/rs1 --port 27017 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64  

mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "2.log" --dbpath /data/rs2 --port 27018 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64 

mongod --replSet m101 --logpath "3.log" --dbpath /data/rs3 --port 27019 --smallfiles --oplogSize 64
```

MongoDB for Unix-like platforms
option **--fork**

> Enables a daemon mode for mongod that runs the process to the
>   background. This is the normal mode of operation, in production and
>   production-like environments, but may not be desirable for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Windows doesn't support the `fork` mechanism like Unix-alikes do, the closest equivalent on Windows would be to run mongod as a service, as explained in [the Mongo manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#mongodb-as-a-windows-service).

Answer (score 1):

In **windows** there is no **fork** command worked since there is alternate to use mongodb as service by using following command:
To Start Service

```
net start mongodb
```

To stop service: Open cmd and use below command

```
net stop mongodb
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The command --fork only works for Linux/Unix. If you need --fork for running mongod in background, on Windows that can be achieved by installing mongod as a service.

When use mongod --install option to install mongodb service, the --dbpath and --logpath are required. In my case, I need use administrator command console to install the service.

For example:

```
mongod --dbpath=C:\mongodb\data --logpath=C:\mongodb\data\log\service.log --install
```

Then browse the log file to see service name and other information including any possible errors.

```
2014-06-25T18:21:14.245-0700 Trying to install Windows service 'MongoDB'
2014-06-25T18:21:14.253-0700 Service 'MongoDB' (MongoDB) installed with command line 'C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.1\bin\mongod.exe --dbpath=C:\mongodb\data --logpath=C:\mongodb\data\log\service.log --service'
2014-06-25T18:21:14.254-0700 Service can be started from the command line with 'net start MongoDB'
```

The default service name is "MongoDB". You can name the service name with --serviceName option when install the service.

Then start the service with net use.

```
net use MongoDB
```

Note when installing the service, it's better to use absolute path for --dbpath and --log. Otherwise the service might have a problem to start. Details have been discussed here: [Cannot start MongoDB as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661670/cannot-start-mongodb-as-a-service)