# MongoDB wouldn't run as a service on Windows 7

Tags: mongodb

I have the issue with running `MongoDB 3.0` service in Windows 7.
I have created the `data/db` and `data/log` inside `MongoDB` root and configured `mongod.conf` file:

**Edited**

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#    http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
    destination: file
    logAppend: true
    path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\log\mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
    dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db
    journal: 
        enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
    fork: true
    pidFilePath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.pid

# network interfaces
# net:
#  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Then I have created a windows service which will run the mongodb on startup:

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "C:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe
 --service --config=C:\MongoDB\mongod.conf" displayname= "MongoDB 3.0 Standard"
start= "auto"
```

I have tried also:

```
sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "\"C:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe\" --service --config=\"C:\MongoDB\mongod.conf\"" DisplayName= "MongoDB" start= "auto"
```

MongoDB service properties show me path to executable:

```
C:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe --service --config=C:\MongoDB\mongod.conf
```

Attempts to run service(net start MongoDB) show me error message:

```
The service is not responding to the control function.
More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2186.
```

I know this issue is quite popular but most of solutions led to wrong paths, file names/extensions which don't solve my problem.

**UPDATE:**

Suggestion to create windows service under specified user doesn't help me as well (the same message during service start):

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sc.exe create MongoDB binPath= "C:\MongoDB\bin\mongod.exe
 --service --config=C:\MongoDB\mongod.conf" displayname= "MongoDB 3.0 Standard"
start= "auto" obj= ".\Administrator" password= "@gdgsfg1"
```

Moreover, I have tried to specify username and password via `services.msc -> MongoDB -> Properties->Log on`

Windows Event log:

```
Error   6.05.2015 19:54:25  Service Control Manager 7009    None
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the MongoDB service to connect.

Error   6.05.2015 19:54:25  Service Control Manager 7000    None
The MongoDB service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Comment: I would start checking with access rights. Mind that when launched in a service it runs by default from a rather limited user. At first try changing it to an administrator (temporarily). To eliminate possibility of access denied. You file locations are rather pretentious: root of system drive

Comment: I have logged in as Administrator, also I have run cmd as Administrator - still the same thing. As for the root of system drive is just temporary decision to avoid problems with path quoting e.g. "C:\Program Files\..." at this moment.

Comment: I am not talking about your work as a UI user. On windows services are usually run from `Local System` account. If your service is properly registered you can find it in services <kbd>Alt+X</kbd>/Computer Managment/Services and Applications/Services

Comment: Examine this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408973/using-sc-exe-to-set-service-credentials-password-failing) for a way to create a service via console (`sc.exe`) and provide a non-default user to run from

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help me, see 'Update' in the post how I tried to do it.

Comment: Did you run the hotfix to [resolve issue with memory mapped files](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/)?

Comment: Yes, hotfix installed and the machine rebooted.

Comment: So far too little info to judge... What does Windows Application Log read about the failed service? There must be at least anything if service fails to start

Comment: I have tried to install windows service by previous instructions from MongoDB 2.4: mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.conf" --install. And i figure out that YAML structure is wrong based on the following error message: Unrecognized option: processManagement.fork

Comment: But I cannot recognize what is actually wrong with processManagement option. I have already check option spelling, spaces. HOWEVER, if I will comment processManagement with all its options, service will run successfully!

Comment: so is your issue resolved?

Comment: Issue is solved despite I didn't understand why processManagement.fork option not work.

Comment: Be so kind as to post your solution as an answer

Comment: Regarding fork not working http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185012/4573999

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77271/discussion-between-kirill-slatin-and-user1376885).

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution why MongoDB service doesn't start successfully.

First of all, install windows mongodb service by this way to see all kind of errors with your `YAML` config file or anything else during service install(sc.exe doesn't provide enough ifnormation during mongodb service install):

```
mongod.exe --config "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.cfg" --install
```

Actually, my issue was with `processManagement.fork` option which is not exist in Windows since it causes error `Unrecognized processManagement.fork option`. So, I have remove this option from my config file and service starts fine.

The final config file:

```
systemLog:  
    destination: file  
    logAppend: true  
    path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\log\mongod.log  
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc  

storage:  
    dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db  
    journal:  
        enabled: true  

processManagement:
    pidFilePath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.pid  

net:  
    port: 27017  
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```